# Convert an object to Array without putting key and value of Object.entries into a string In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to convert an object like this:

```
let obj = {
arabicLang: false,
cancelVisitEmailAlert: false,
canselVisitSmsAlert: false
}
```

into an array of key-value pairs like this:

```
[
"arabicLang": false,
"cancelVisitEmailAlert": false,
"canselVisitSmsAlert": false
]
```

I read all questions in StackOverflow but none of them is my case

i try this but it return key and value in string:

```
    let data = [];
     for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
       data.push(createData(key, value));
     }

function createData(key, value) {
    return key + ":" + value;
  }
```

and also try this:

```
    let arr = Array.of(obj)
      console.log(arr) 
      /* output is 
      [{
    arabicLang: false,
    cancelVisitEmailAlert: false,
    canselVisitSmsAlert: false
    }]

*/
```

it keeps the object container

Comment: `arabicLang: false` as an element won't work (it's a syntax error), do you want this to be an object: `{arabicLang: false}`?

Comment: I think that you cannot create an `Array` like this, if you wanna create an `Array` of `objects` use `Object.entries(obj)` that will result in `[{a: 1}, {b:2}]`

Comment: All object keys in Javascript are strings, the quotes are not needed for convenience when writing object literals.

Comment: You could use Object.entries() and flat the result but the result will be comma seperated and not `semicolon comma semicolon comma`

Comment: Since `[arabicLang: false]` is invalid syntax we can't really know what you expect it to do. Why do you want an array instead of an object? How do you plan to use that value? Maybe that helps understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I can't think of any use case where this is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce` or `.map` like:

```js
let obj = {
    arabicLang: false,
    cancelVisitEmailAlert: false,
    canselVisitSmsAlert: false
};

// Using .reduce
const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc[key] ??= {[key]: value};
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(Object.values(result));

// Using .map
const result2 = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}));
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing instead of `createData` method, just use object literal to simplify.

```js
let obj = {
  arabicLang: false,
  cancelVisitEmailAlert: false,
  canselVisitSmsAlert: false,
};

let data = [];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  data.push({ [key]: value });
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Just `Object.entries` will produce the wanted result.

Comment: Object.entries will produce like [[key1, val1], [key2, val2]] right? here if we need it like array of objects.

Comment: Probably, but the OP's notation is invalid, and makes it confusing. To me an *"array of key-value pairs"* is what `Object.entries` returns.